# Trying to add Koin DI to my Android app but the startKoin method is not recognized

Tags: android, koin

I added Koin to the Gradle file:

```
    def koin_version = '2.0.1'
    // Koin for Android
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
    // Koin Android Scope feature
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-scope:$koin_version"
    // Koin Android ViewModel feature
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:$koin_version"
    // Koin Android Experimental features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-ext:$koin_version"
```

I added a appModules class but when I try to add the startKoin method the to Application, it's not recognized.

```
startKoin{
        androidLogger()
        androidContext(this@MyApplication)
        modules(appModule)
    }
```

I get the 'Cannot resolve symbol' error there. I tried to add the import manually but also there I get an error. Anyone with an idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this dependency in Build.gradle(app module)

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-android-architecture:0.9.1"
```